# Denoiser node does not work in Blender 2.82

Tags: denoise

In Blender 2.82, Intel Open Image Denoise does not seem to work as when I try to denoise an image using the denoiser node, the resulting image is completely black.

I recall the denoiser node working as expected in Blender 2.81. So if that’s the case, is this a bug for this Blender release?

Comment: I've had no problems with the Denoiser node in 2.82, so you would need to provide more info or a blend file for us to be able to help. You can upload the file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your compositing nodes.